# Unable to obtain OAuth 2 access token

Tags: twitter, python-2.7, twython

I'm working on a GUI to read tweets, based on python 2.7.

When I run the script via Eclipse an PyDev, everything works fine. But after compiling it with gui2exe/py2exe, I get this error message:

```
twython.exceptions.TwythonAuthError: Unable to obtain OAuth 2 access token
```

The code is:

```
CONSUMER_KEY = '****'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = '****'
    ACCESS_KEY = '****'
    ACCESS_SECRET = '****'
    twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, oauth_version=2)
    ACCESS_TOKEN = twitter.obtain_access_token()
    if settings.value("Proxys").toBool() == True:
        httpproxy = settings.value ("HttpProxy").toString()
        httpsproxy = settings.value ("HttpsProxy").toString()
        proxystring = "'http': '%s','https': '%s'" % (httpproxy, httpsproxy)
        client_args = {
                       'proxies': {
                                   proxystring,
                                   }
                       }
        self.api = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, client_args=client_args)
    else:
        self.api = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

Can anyone help?